# Best practices for receiving server exception messages on ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, exception

The essence of my question is this: If I issue a $.ajax request to my server for server-side validation -- how should I expect to handle the validation response? I see myself as having two options:

```
//  Server handled error:
$.ajax({
   url: 'controller/action',
   data: {},
   success: function(response){
       console.log("Error:", response.error);
   }
}

//  Server unhandled error:
$.ajax({
   url: 'controller/action',
   data: {},
   success: function(){
   },
   error: function(error){
       console.log("Error:", error);
   }
}
```

The former example assumes that my server's controller has a try/catch which consumes any server-side exceptions. It then takes any exceptions and returns them as part of the json success object. The latter allows the server's exception to bubble up through and be caught in the ajax error handler.

Personally, I thought I preferred the latter. However, I just encountered an issue with remoting -- if our server's security settings aren't relaxed then the error message gets hidden as a 'Runtime Error' and reading the error information from the ajax's onerror event handler becomes impossible.

I would like to avoid that issue, I need to always be able to read my errors, but it seems **really wrong** to have my ajax request always return successful.

How is this normally handled?

```
[HttpPost, AjaxOnly]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordDialogModel model)
{
    string error = string.Empty;

    if (model.NewPassword == model.NewPasswordConfirm)
    {
        using (var service = new SecurityServicesSoapClient())
        {
            error = service.ChangePassword(SessionManager.Default.User.UserName, model.OldPassword,
                                           model.NewPassword);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        error = "New Password and Confirm do not match. Please re-enter";
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        throw new Exception(error);

    return Json(new
        {
            success = true
        });
}
```

This versus setting success to false and setting an error property to the error message.

Comment: Personally I treat the client-side and server-side code as separate applications.  The former is simply accessing an API on the latter.  As such, I want to make sure the server-side application (like any application) _never_ has unhandled exceptions.  If there's an error condition that it needs to communicate to a client, it should do so in a structure familiar to that client.  In HTTP, that would be error codes and response bodies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do something quite similar in my system. Success always returns data like:

```
$data['success'] = array(/* your data to be served back to the page */); //PHP
```

whereas errors are always done like:

```
$data['errors'] = array(/* your error data */); //PHP
```

You can set flags to look for exception codes in your controller catch() statements to filter types of error messages. In your JS code you just do:

```
// JS
$.ajax({success:function(data) {
    if (data.success !== undefined) {}
    else if (data.errors !== undefined) {}
}});
```

You can get crazier and add them as global AJAX handlers as well by adding this code to a `$(document).ajaxComplete();` callback.

You can and should have a separate handler for the ajax error callback, because that can include situations that your controller code has no control over (404 errors, server unreachable, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this to check error for ajax calls.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'controller/action',
   data: {},
   success: function(){
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR.status);
    }
}
```

Depending on `jqXHR.status` value, you can show customized error message.